# Проблема с доступом к ресурсам integer в android

Tags: java, android, ресурсы

Здравствуйте!

Создала в папке \app\src\main\res файл integers.xml следующего содержания:

```
    <resources>
        <integer name="figure_height">85</integer>
        <integer name="figure_width">85</integer>
    </resources>
```

Пытаюсь в коде эти ресурсы получить. Этот код не работает, и еще до компиляции подчеркивает красным.

```
   Resources res = context.getResources();
   int figure_height = res.getInteger(android.R.integer.figure_height);
```

Подскажите как правильно добраться до ресурсов.

Comment: а префикс `android.` зачем?

Comment: Я пишу просто R, но при написании intellij idea сама добавляет префикс

Answer (score 5, accepted):

надо не android.R, а your_package.R, где your_package - ну вы поняли.

android.R - это системный список ресурсов.

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло.

Comment: @Анна отметьте решением, галочка слева.